# Private Nuget Server: I can't see my packages from Nuget Package Explorer

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server, nuget-spec, nugetgallery

I followed the Microsoft official [Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/nuget/hosting-packages/nuget-server) for create a Private Nuget Server. Everything seems to work, I can see my packages feed from browser and I can see my packages from Visual Studio package manager. However when I try to push, read or create new package from Nuget Package Explore as explained [Here](http://rion.io/2014/07/20/using-the-nuget-package-explorer-to-create-explore-and-publish-packages/) , It seems that the atom feed isn't getting started. I received the following error "The expected property 'Published' could not found while processing Atom results"

N.B. I've created this packages some time ago with a previous version of Nuget Package Explorer. Do you think I should re-create all packages with the new version? I hope not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the feed working again in Nuget Package Manager by updating the EntityPropertyMapping for "Published" to keepInContent: true in the ODataPackage.cs file. I'm using Nuget.Server v2.14.0.0.

```
[EntityPropertyMapping("Published", SyndicationItemProperty.Published, SyndicationTextContentKind.Plaintext, keepInContent: true)]
```

The Date published also shows now in the NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio with this change.

Answer (score 0):

Some weeks ago I just created my server following the same Microsoft official Guide and I had no issues using Nuget Package Explorer...

The difference with you is that I have created (and pushed) my package using another approach (automatically with [CakeBuild](http://cakebuild.net/))...

Could you please provide us more details about:

- your Private Nuget Server
- the Nuget version you used to publish your packages
- the Nuget Package Explorer version you are using

Comment: Belove some informations:

- My Private Server is an ASP.Net web application deployed on IIS 7.5 (I've downloaded it from nuget [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Server/2.11.3/))
- Nuget Package Explorer version 3.21.0.0
- Nuget private Server version 2.11.3

N:B: I had to do a version upgrade of private Nuget Server, from 1.8.0 
because I found an existing installation compromised, 
I could create and make the push for new packages but I could not see the feed. So existing packs were created with this version. Now I not able to push and create packages but I can see the feed

Comment: I correct myself: I can  see feed but only from browser or from Visual Studio Nuget Package Manager.  I can't see my feed from Nuget Package Explorer.

Comment: Ok Davide, now I can see that you are using a different version of Nuget Server of mine (but don't know if this is the cause). I'm using the older v2.10.3 (targetted for .NET 4.5) because my web server hasn't .NET framework 4.6 installed and can't install it so fast. I'm pretty sure the 'Published' property IS NOT set inside the nuget package... it is a property coming from server or nuget package explorer...

Comment: Ok Luca thank for your support. If I find a solution I will write it. For now I have resolved pushing packages by command line.

Comment: Ok! So, if you didn't touch your server and only used another publishing approach then the issue seems related to Nuget Package Manager... You can try to open an issue on its github project.